# Azure: Get a row key value from a table and display it as a token number

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I need to get a row key value from a table and display it as a token number in logic apps. Is there any possibility for this? please let me know if any.

I have tried to get entity and display but it's asking row key as input. So I am not getting any idea what to do.

Comment: Any process on this issue, could you solve it with my way?

Comment: hi george thanks for helping out. could you please provide a solution for another question which i have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Get Entities` to implement it, this action supports `Filter Query` and `Select Query`

OData filter query is for which entities to return and OData select query is for the columns to be returned.

So you could in the filter query use like `PartitionKey eq '001'` to get the entities and in the select query use `RowKey` then it will only return the RowKey of all entities.

[image]

[image]